# Jquery Inputmask formatted decimal number to integer value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

Im using `inputmask` with jquery. And it is working well to me but when I submit my form, input's value is sending me `string` like **15,000$** but my model field is `integer`. I want to be it simple `integer` number.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" data-mask="rcurrency" data-sign="$">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

How can I do that with?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a integer.

```
var number = '15,000$';
parseInt(number.replace(/,|\$/g, ''));
```